# Copy filtered data to another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, copy

I have two sheets. One has the complete data and the other is based on the filter applied on the first sheet.

Name of the data sheet : `Data`
Name of the filtered Sheet : `Hoky`

I am just taking a small portion of data for simplicity.  MY objective is to copy the data from Data Sheet, based on the filter.  I have a macro which somehow works but its hard-coded and is a recorded macro.

My problems are:

1. The number of rows is different everytime. (manual effort)
2. Columns are not in order.

[image]
[image]

```
Sub TESTTHIS()
'
' TESTTHIS Macro
'
'FILTER
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$F$12").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="hockey"

'Data Selection and Copy
Range("C3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hockey").Select
Range("E3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("D3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hockey").Select
Range("D3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("E3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hockey").Select
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Best way of doing it**

Below code is to copy the visible data in DBExtract sheet, and paste it into duplicateRecords sheet, with only filtered values. Range selected by me is the maximum range that can be occupied by my data. You can change it as per your need.

```
  Sub selectVisibleRange()

    Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DuplicateRecords")

    DbExtract.Range("A1:BF9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial


    End Sub
```

Comment: SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When i need to copy data from filtered table i use range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy. Where the range is range of all data (without a filter).

Example:

```
Sub copy()
     'source worksheet
     dim ws as Worksheet
     set ws = Application.Worksheets("Data")' set you source worksheet here
     dim data_end_row_number as Integer
     data_end_row_number = ws.Range("B3").End(XlDown).Row.Number
    'enable filter
    ws.Range("B2:F2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="hockey", VisibleDropDown:=True
    ws.Range("B3:F" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Application.Worksheets("Hoky").Range("B3").Paste
    'You have to add headers to Hoky worksheet
end sub
```

Comment: Can you write an example (complete lne of code)so that i can apply it on my sheet.

Comment: @AnanyaPandey  This isn't a "free code writing service".  Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: With all due respect Mister, I am not asking for free service, I tried i failed and seeking help here i am learning, Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it a different way.

In the following code I set as a `Range` the column with the sports name F and [loop through each cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) of it, check if it is "hockey" and if yes I insert the values in the other sheet one by one, by using [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

I do not think it is very complicated and even if you are just learning VBA, you should probably be able to understand every step. Please let me know if you need some clarification

```
Sub TestThat()

'Declare the variables
Dim DataSh As Worksheet
Dim HokySh As Worksheet
Dim SportsRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As Long

'Set the variables
Set DataSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set HokySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoky")

Set SportsRange = DataSh.Range(DataSh.Cells(3, 6), DataSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
    'I went from the cell row3/column6 (or F3) and go down until the last non empty cell

    i = 2

    For Each rCell In SportsRange 'loop through each cell in the range

        If rCell = "hockey" Then 'check if the cell is equal to "hockey"

            i = i + 1                                'Row number (+1 everytime I found another "hockey")
            HokySh.Cells(i, 2) = i - 2               'S No.
            HokySh.Cells(i, 3) = rCell.Offset(0, -1) 'School
            HokySh.Cells(i, 4) = rCell.Offset(0, -2) 'Background
            HokySh.Cells(i, 5) = rCell.Offset(0, -3) 'Age

        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked fine. Thanks. and i got the idea although i have to know more about the offset function.

Comment: This is a very time consuming process and take lot of time to read each row and copy it to another sheet, Sheet will hang when you have data in thousands record

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be .Row.count not Row.Number?

That's what I used and it works fine
Sub TransfersToCleared()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Export (2)") 'Data Source
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A2:AB" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy