# Is it possible to get filtered results from another sheet dynamically without kutools?

Tags: excel

I need to dynamically transfer filtered results from one sheet to another. A quick google search yielded as a result only one way to do this with a paid excel addon, called kutools. Is there another way to achieve this, without getting empty lines.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text",Sheet1!A1)),Sheet1!A1,"")
```

Something like this is my backup option, but I'd like to find out if there is another better way for this task, that wouldn't leave me with a bunch of empty lines i have to sort.

Comment: In general, copying filtered results to another sheet is a quite achieveable task with VBA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-macros

Comment: @Vityata We're talking about an online excel file and macro is not an option there.

Comment: How do you think "KUTools" has built its add-in?

Comment: I'm guessing the way you suggest. Problem is that this needs to be solved in an online sheet, there is no way to apply extensions or macros to it. Its a seriously stripped down version of excel.

Answer (score 3):

Try this tiny trick.  It will work if there are no empties in column **B**.
 No addins; no VBA; no additional array formulas are required for the trick.

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

We want to apply a filter and extract the visible data elsewhere.

First in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B2)=0,MIN($C$1:C1)-1,SUBTOTAL(3,$B$2:$B2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

This is a nice sequential list.  Now set the filter for column **B** to display ***2***:
[image]

The "helper" column has adjusted to retain its nice sequential nature.

In another sheet we can now use a typical `INDEX/MATCH` to get the data.

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$22,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C$1:C$22,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

*(with VBA, a "helper" column is not necessary)*

**EDIT#1:**

If you do not want to use *AutoFilter* and just grab the records for which column **B** has the value ***2***, then in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2=2,1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

and if you want to to grab all the records **except** the ***2*** records, use this "helper" formula:

```
=IF(B2<>2,1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

Comment: Clever solution. Only disadvantage is that `SUBTOTAL(3,...)` returns 0 if the cell is hidden *or blank*. So if there are blank cells in your data then this might not work. Although, as long as at least one column of data is *never* blank, then you can base the `SUBTOTAL` formula off of that column and it will work with no issues. Still, amazing solution. +1

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889  **THANK YOU** ...................I will add the restriction

Comment: @Gary's Student. Thanks for the solution. I realize now that I might not have formulated the title in the most exact way. This does what its supposed to do in an awesome way. To use your example, what I actually need is to filter out all the b column 2s to sheet2, regardless of what is being done to sheet1 and only them. And that should work for new entries too. As it stand it just changes depending on what you do in sheet1.

Comment: @cybera  It is very easy to grab only the ***2*** records or to grab everything except the ***2*** records just by changing the "helper" formula.

Comment: @Gary's Student. Seems like I'm not explaining properly. Let me try again. So people are constantly creating new entries to sheet1, filling in and editing stuff. I need some of those lines to be dynamically filled into sheet2 as they are created without interrupting the work on sheet1. To get the data I need with your way I need to apply a filter to sheet1, and the information I need is properly filled in to sheet2 only while this filter is applied. So I have to stop everyone else's work to work on sheet 2 and my progress would actually not save the data will change when the filter is removed.

Comment: @cybera  I think I understand................ see my **EDIT#1** ...............the Users can add/remove/edit records  in *Sheet1* to their heart's content and *Sheet2*  will automatically adjust to the changing records!

Comment: @Gary's Student. This does the same as the backup I had posted in the original post. It gets the relevant lines, but fills in empty lines where there are no matches. I'm gonna guess that what I was looking for is just not possible. Thank you for the effort.