# Trouble copying rows to next empty row in different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm having trouble with an assignment.

I'm having this sheet with 18287 students. One in each row. They have individual person ID's, they have different campus', they've been enrolled for their education at different times etc. etc.

I'm building a loop-code, that finds the students that are delayed and have been rolled back. If they are delayed, the H column has to be below 133. Equally i'm looking for students currently studying a bachelor degree. Which means that column L must be "Bachelor". My loop looks like this at the time:

```
for i = 2 to 18288
If worksheets(1).range(i,5)<133 and worksheets(1).range(i,11)="Bachelor" then
worksheets(1).row(i).copy
```

I'm trying to copy the row to the first empty row in worksheet (Delayed Students). I've tried many different approaches. Some of them don't copy anything, other attempts has resulted in excel shutting down... I've searched Google, and what I've concluded is that the .select, .copy, .paste procedures are very demanding, and could cause a crash.

So i'm looking for a code, where I don't necessarily have to copy the rows. Any help with that, I'm running out of possible solutions myself..?

[image: Base]

Comment: Did you ever think about filtering column H < 133 and L for "Bachelor"? I think filters are much easier and should even be faster. After filtering you can use [Copy filtered data to another sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-vba)

Comment: No I haven't. I'm still pretty new to vba, didn't knew filtering were a possibility, I'm giving it a try, Thx.

Comment: Also `range(i,5)` is not valid syntax, it should be `cells(i,5)`  or `Range("E" & i)`.

Comment: And another thing... E=5 and K=11.

Comment: Well, that just solved everything. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RasmusHolmStruve You should have a look into the answers below for faster solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever think about filtering column H < 133 and L for "Bachelor"? I think filters are much easier and should even be faster.

```
With Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<133", Operator:=xlAnd
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="=Bachelor", Operator:=xlAnd
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
Worksheets("SheetToPasteIn").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: `AutoFilter` is very fast :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Well, even faster than copy row by row

Answer (score 0):

The most consuming time for the code is to access the Worksheet, like the `Copy` command. You can minimize by using a `CopyRng` object to merge all the `Rows` that pass your criteria, using the `Union` function.

At the end you just `Copy` the entire range at once.

**Note**: column "H" using the `Range` in your loop should be `Range("H" & i)`, and not `range(i,5)`. The same for the other case.

Try the modified code below:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 2 To 18288
        If .Range("H" & i).Value < 133 And .Range("K" & i).Value2 = "Bachelor" Then
            If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Rows(i))
            Else
                Set CopyRng = .Rows(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

' check at least 1 rows in the Range
If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then CopyRng.Copy
```