# Listbox not showing the values that were populated in it using Listbox.List method

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

After running the `Userform_Initialize()` event, there would be nothing populated in the listbox as shown below:

[image]

There should be 11 columns populating the listbox based on the excel table below:

[image]

The code ran:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Total_rows_FoilProfile As Long
Dim row As Range, i As Long

Total_rows_FoilProfile = TotalRowsCount(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Foil Profile", "tblFoilProfile")

ReDim MyArr(0 To Total_rows_FoilProfile - 1)

For Each row In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
    MyArr(i) = row.Value
    i = i + 1
Next row

lbxFoilInfoDisplay.List = MyArr

frmFoilPanel.Show
```

The properties of the listbox:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks that makes sense, but how do I populate the listbox with the table above though? Does it makes sense if I make a nested `for-next` loop that loops through the row and columns so each cell in the table would be assigned to one cell in the array instead? Will the `Listbox.list` method work from there if I assign to it `MyArr(5, 11)`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Yes actually, the combo boxes shown in the userform acts like a filtering mechanism that dynamically updates the listbox which i'll fire using the `After_Update()` events of each combo box but I don't know how to populate the list using VBA because `RowSource` method uses an excel string formula as an argument which will not work because i'm using `Autofilter`. I have a work around of having a helper worksheet use `PasteSpecial` then use that as my listbox input, but I believe it's computationally taxing given I have to update that worksheet for each combo box that is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate each list row and then add the columns to it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tblFoilProfile As ListObject
    Set tblFoilProfile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile")

    Dim i As Long

    lbxFoilInfoDisplay.Clear

    Dim iListRow As Range
    For Each iListRow In tblFoilProfile.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        With Me.lbxFoilInfoDisplay
            .AddItem iListRow.Cells(1, 1).Value 'add first value (column 1)

            Dim iCol As Long
            For iCol = 2 To iListRow.Columns.Count 'add all other columns to that row
                .list(i, iCol) = iListRow.Cells(1, iCol).Value '.Value for unformatted value or .Text to show it in the same format as in the cell
            Next iCol
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next iListRow
End Sub
```

Note here is a [nice guide how to work with list objects](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

Comment: I am getting a `Could not set the List property. Invalid property value.` When `iCol = 10` and `iListRow = 0` at the `.list(i, iCol) = iListRow.Cells(1, iCol).Value` using the data table shown above for some reason. I never knew you could populate a list similarly to an array though and that it starts at row 0. Thanks

Comment: I'll check around on my data maybe there's some format that makes it unable to add to the list. But I think this should work

Comment: Check the value of `iListRow.Cells(1, iCol).Value` when the error occurs. This should work. I assume there is an error in the cell. Use either `.list(i, iCol) = CStr(iListRow.Cells(1, iCol).Value)` or `.list(i, iCol) = iListRow.Cells(1, iCol).Text` (to show the value in the same format as it was shown in the cell).

Comment: Thanks still working on finding why it's failing. I tried the other two to try convert it to string, but still the same issue. But what's weird is that it's the same text of `TEST` could the listbox have a limit on the number of columns? I found this there is indeed a 9 column limit https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/104880-listbox-error-380-too-many-columns.html

Comment: I'll just create a 2nd listbox to work around it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Pherdindy Ah, didn't remember the limit, my bad. Two workarounds for that: Since the 10-column limit (0 to 9) is *only for an unbound data source* you can use a hidden sheet to put your filtered data in and then link that range to your listbox. Linked ranges work with more than 10 columns. The other option you have is create 2 listboxes and syncronize the lists. I would prefer the first one.

Comment: The 1st was also the workaround I was planning to use initially if that can work and pass the limit then i'll stick with it. I was just initially trying to find a more efficient way but I think this is as efficient as it can get because all my spreadsheets end up extremely slow. Thanks

Comment: @Pherdindy Note that you don't even need to loop to [copy the filtered range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807755/3219613). Which makes it even easier.