# Copying already-filtered data with variable number of rows into new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a filtered worksheet (ActionRegister) and I want to copy only the filtered (visible) cells into a new worksheet, within the same Workbook, called Duplicate. The actual data starts from Row 4 onwards (above rows are headers) and there are a variable number of rows, but always columns A:Q.

I have no experience with VBA and am really struggling to find a solution. I've seen code for copying into a new workbook etc. but my background is so limited I can't even modify this for my purposes.

Could someone please provide code that can copy only visible/already filtered cells and ignore the headers for a variable number of rows? Thank you!! :)

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-vba already?

Comment: Also, when asking in Stackoverflow it's a good practice to post what you've already tried.

Comment: I appreciate this feedback but I have tried literally nothing as I have 0 experience with VBA and can't understand the syntax. I also did look at that one (trawled through the web for about 4 hours looking at different solutions) but my maximum range is >22000, is variable and updated daily and hence was not applicable to my question. I agree that if I had a bit of knowledge I should be able to modify it but unfortunately I do not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub makeDuplicate()

    application.displayalerts = false
    on error resume next
    worksheets("Duplicate").delete
    on error goto 0
    application.displayalerts = true

    dim target as range

    with worksheets.add(after:=worksheets("ActionRegister"))
        .name = "Duplicate"
        set target = .cells(1)
    end with

    with worksheets("ActionRegister")

        intersect(.range("A:Q"), .usedrange.offset(3, 0), .usedrange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy _
          destination:=target

    end with

end sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but it does not copy only the visible/filtered cells and instead just copies the entire worksheet. Is there a way to include `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` here? That is the only issue

Comment: I've made the modification but copying and pasting filtered rows should only transfer the visible data, not the hidden rows.

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you so much.
Not sure if it makes a difference but the spreadsheet itself that I am copying from is auto-filtered via a macro so maybe that has something to do with it? Regardless, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try following sub.

```
Sub cpVisible()
Dim MyProdName As String
Dim FilteredRange As Range
Dim myArr As Variant

    Sheets("ActionRegister").Range("$A$4:$Q$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="IT"
    Set FilteredRange = Sheets("ActionRegister").Range("$A$4:$Q$50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    FilteredRange.Copy Sheets("Duplicate").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

You need to change criteria `(Criteria1:="IT")` and column number `(Field:=2)` if you want to filter data based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this patch of code will do it for you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Copy_Columns()


    Dim r As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim lLast_Row1 As Long
    Dim lLast_Row2 As Long
     'identify the columns and copy the data
    With Worksheets("Raw").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        Set r = Application.Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(2), .Columns(7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    With Worksheets("Output")
        Set r2 = .Range("B8:D8").Resize(.Range("B6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

        r2.Clear
        r.Copy r2.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1)

         'extend the formulas
        lLast_Row1 = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lLast_Row2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If lLast_Row2 > lLast_Row1 Then
            .Range("E" & lLast_Row1).Resize((lLast_Row2 - lLast_Row1) + 1, 6).FillDown
        End If         
    End With     
End Sub
```