# Filter and copy data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem filtering the date from the first sheet of a workbook and then copying everything in another workbook. In the first part of my code, I'm selecting the workbook I want to work with. When I'm running my code it just copies all the data, without filtering it and i don't know what it's wrong about it.

```
Sub macro()

Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Range("A1:CA" & LastRow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=39, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "0", "1", "2", "3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=1/1/2018", _
                        Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                        Criteria2:="<=12/31/2019"
    Selection.Copy
    Cells.Select

    Dim dest As Range
    With Workbooks("data.xlsm").Worksheets(3)

    Sheets("data").Range("A:CA").ClearContents

    Set dest = .Range("A1")
    Selection.Copy dest
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
' Close customer workbook
customerWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy filtered data to another sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-vba)

Comment: You are doing a lot of `Select` (which @TimStack reply should cover) but no where are you specifying which workbook you want to work with (i.e. `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`.. this could be your `customerWorkbook` workbook or the one you are opening). Try to be specific on which workbook you want to refer to. Also, have a look at `With` statement

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Activate is the one i'm opening.

Comment: @MaziluIsabelaElena you don't understand, that is only the sheet you are specifying. A sheet with name "Sheet1" could be present in any workbook. You will have to specify the WB as well, e.g. by `Workbooks(customerFilename).Sheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just need to add Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy instead of Selection.Copy in your code.