# Filtered dataset not getting pasted in the destination sheet properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste my filtered dataset to different sheets(already created) based on the filter criteria. Each destination sheet has appropriate header information in a table so I will just paste the filtered dataset in those sheets. The issue I am facing is whenever I paste the filtered dataset from the stored range variable, it's pasting everything(both filtered data and unfiltered data). Since my destination sheet has table in it, to avoid duplicate data or unwanted data, I first clear the table and then paste my filtered data. But every single time I paste data, it dumps everything instead of just the filtered dataset. Any idea why this might be happening?

I have tried filtering in a different method but irrespective of what filtering criteria I use, excel keeps populating my destination table with all the data from the raw sheet.

```
Sub Formulae()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh_raw As Worksheet
Dim sh_cart As Worksheet
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xWs As Worksheet

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set sh_cart = wb.Sheets("Cart Information")

''Checking if the Raw_Data sheet exists or not. If not exists, then MACRO aborts and prompts the user to run the import macro first.

For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name Like "Raw*" Then flg = True: Exit For
Next
If flg = True Then
GoTo Start:
Else
MsgBox "No Raw Data Sheet exists!!! Please run the 'Import' Macro First."
GoTo ResetSettings:
End If

Start:

Set sh_raw = wb.Sheets("Raw_Data") 'My source data resides in this raw datasheet

With sh_raw
    .Range("G1").Value = "Section"
    .Range("G2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP([@[IP_Address]],Cart_Information,6,0)"
    '.Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End With

'sh_raw.Cells.AutoFit

'Here I will filter the raw data set based on the section list in another sheet
sh_cart.Activate
Set Rng = Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown)) 'Setting the criteria list inside a range

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng) 'Storing the range in an array by transposing the list

'Now I"ll filter the base table according to my filter list
For Each item In myarr
    sh_raw.Activate
    'Debug.Print item

    '''I wanna copy only the visible range below the header from the filtered raw data set
    sh_raw.ListObjects("ELMS").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=item
    'Set r2 = sh_raw.ListObjects("ELMS").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 1)
    'Set r2 = Range(r2, r2.End(xlToRight))
    'Set r2 = Range(r2, r2.End(xlDown))

    Set r1 = sh_raw.ListObjects("ELMS").AutoFilter.Range
    Set r2 = Intersect(r1.Offset(1, 0), r1) 'storing the filtered range without the header in r2 range variable

    '''Looping through each template sheets which are named after the filter criteria list
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name = item Then
        xWs.Activate

            With xWs
                '.Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter
                .Range("A2:Q2", Range("A2:Q2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents 'Clearing the table first in case there is data from previous run
                '.Range("A2").Select
                '.Range("A2:Q2", Range("A2:Q2").End(xlDown)).Delete
            End With
        r2.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2") 'Now pasting the stored data in the template table

        ''Also I'm pasting all the required formulae in the sheet for making a pivot table & chart based on the filtered dataset
            With xWs
                    .Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                    .Range("H2").Formula = "=INT(E2)" 'since this is a table, the formula gets autofilled throughout the cells
                    '.Range("H2", "H" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("I2").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Hour"",B2)),MAX(0,IF(AND(D3=D2,B3=B2),C3-C2,0),),"""")"
                    '.Range("I2", "I" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("J2").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Hour"",B2)),MIN(IF(HOUR($E2)=20,4,IF(HOUR($E2)=0,8,IF(HOUR($E2)=4,12,IF(HOUR($E2)=8,16,0)))),MAX(0,IF(AND(D2=D1,B2=B1),C2-C1,0),)),"""")"
                    '.Range("J2", "J" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    '.Range("K2").Formula = "=INT(E2)" 'Dummy formula for now
                    '.Range("K2", "K" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("L2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX([Field_Value],MATCH(1,(""Test_Location""=[Field_Name])*([@[IP_Address]]=[IP_Address])*([@[Poll_Date]]=[Poll_Date]),0))"
                    '.Range("L2", "L" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("K2").FormulaArray = "=IF([@Channel]=0,"""",INDEX(Cycler_Channel[[1]:[8]],MATCH([@Cycler],Cycler_Channel[Cycler],0),[@Channel]))" ''Actual formula is used
                    '.Range("K2", "K" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("K2", Range("K2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = 0
                    .Range("M2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX([Field_Value],MATCH(1,(""TC_IPaddress""=[Field_Name])*([@[IP_Address]]=[IP_Address])*([@[Poll_Date]]=[Poll_Date])*([@Channel]=[Channel]),0))"
                    '.Range("M2", "M" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("N2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX([Field_Value],MATCH(1,(""UUTID""=[Field_Name])*([@[IP_Address]]=[IP_Address])*([@[Poll_Date]]=[Poll_Date])*([@Channel]=[Channel]),0))"
                    '.Range("N2", "N" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Value = "TBD"
                    .Range("P2", Range("P2").End(xlDown)).Value = "TBD"
                    .Range("Q2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,Cart_Information,5,FALSE)"
                    '.Range("Q2", "Q" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown 'filling the entire column with the formula
                    .Cells.Columns.AutoFit

            End With
        End If
    Next

Next item

'Refreshing the pivot table once pivot tables have been updated with latest data
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each pt In WS.PivotTables
          pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt

    Next WS

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes.", vbInformation ''Displaying the information for macro execution time

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

I expect my code to paste only the filtered data in the destination table but it pastes the whole raw dataset even though I specifically store the filtered dataset in a range variable.

Comment: 1) Avoid using `GoTo` - that creates spaghetti code. 2) You're probably looking for `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy filtered data to another sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-vba)

Comment: BigBen, I have done that as you can see I have commented it out. The problem with that one is it skips some of the rows below the header for some reason!!! It works if the 2nd row is visible below the header then no issue but if let's say 1665th row is visible below the header after filtering, then it captures a random range.