# How do I copy cells withput making a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

As a continue to this question: [Copy filtered data to another sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121960/copy-filtered-data-to-another-sheet-using-vba?newreg=7ceb461666b44f55a31136d249ba6a02)

The selected solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807755/21341069 is creating a new sheet.
There is a way to copy the data to an exists sheet?

**UPDATE**
The problem cause because other part in the code. You can close the question.

Thank you!

I try to replace the `copy` with `move` but it doesn't run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which sheet and where you want it, you'll have to adjust it but the only change you need to make to the code you found is setting of the sheet since it doesn't create a new sheet at all, those sheets exists already:

```
Sub selectVisibleRange()

    Dim DbExtract As Worksheet, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet") 'Export Worksheet is an existing sheet
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DuplicateRecords") 'DuplicateRecords is an existing sheet

    DbExtract.Range("A1:BF9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'copies the visible cells only (like when rows/columns are hidden or filtered out)
'you'd be better off working with lRow though
    DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial 'pastes the values in A1 in the existing sheet

End Sub
```

With the lRow added:

```
Sub selectVisibleRange()

    Dim DbExtract As Worksheet, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
    lRow = DbExtract.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DuplicateRecords")

    DbExtract.Range("A1:BF" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Hope that's clear to understand like this :)

Comment: Not working :-\ it's creating a new sheet :-(

Comment: Have you changed "Export Worksheet" to your desired sheet where to copy from and "DuplicateRecords" to your desired sheet to paste your data in?

Comment: Yes, I try to put easy names :) I hope it's OK.

Comment: No idea then what you're doing wrong, I can't reproduce your issue as this code works perfectly fine in my created test-file. It shouldn't create a new sheet. Can you go through your code step by step with `F8` in VBE and see where your issue is exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! at other part of my code I had this line: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet3")` (with other names....) and this what make it. 
Sorry! But thank you for all your help!

Comment: No need to apologize, you're learning and that's what's important :)